# Printing primes less than 100?

Tags: python, list, printing, primes

I am new to programming and trying to write a program that prints primes less than 100. When I run my program I get an output that has most of the prime numbers, but I also have even numbers and random odd numbers. Here is my code:

---

```
a=1
while a<100:
    if a%2 == 0:
        a+=1
    else:
        for i in range(2,int(a**.5)+1):
            if a%i != 0:
                print a
                a+=1
            else:
                a+=1
```

---

The first part of my code is meant to eliminate all even numbers (doesn't seem to fully work). I also don't fully understand the part of my code (for i in).

What exactly does the "for i in" part of the code do? What is 'i'?

How can I modify my code that it does accurately find all of the primes from 1-100?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A hint: your program prints a number as soon as it finds *one* other number that it's not divisible by.  But what you need is to only print numbers if they're not divisible by *any* other numbers.

Comment: You are using confusing terms; do you want to find the first 100 primes, or all primes below 100?

Comment: it iterates from `2` to `sqrt(a)`

Comment: You are also incrementing `a` in all the wrong places. Do so in one place only, before testing the next number. Better still, just use a `for a in range(100):` loop and not increment it at all. Use `continue` to skip the rest of the loop.

Comment: This doesn't produce any output at all. It just hangs with a=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments on your post to find out why your code doesn't work. I'm just here to fix your code.

---

First of all, make use of functions. They make code so much more readable. In this case, a function to check if a number is a prime would be a good idea.

```
from math import sqrt

def is_prime(number):
    return all(number%i for i in range(2, int(sqrt(number))+1))
```

There isn't much left to do now - all you need is to count how many primes you've found, and a number that keeps growing:

```
primes= 0
number= 1
while primes<100:
    if is_prime(number):
        print number
        primes+= 1
    number+= 1 # or += 2 for more speed.
```

Suddenly it's very easy to read and debug, is it not?

Comment: I am running Python 2 since I am doing the MIT course on Python. It comes up with a syntax error on the "for" part of the statement. Is this only a validate syntax on Python 3?

Comment: @TomJones: The code works in both python2 and python3 (if you fix the `print`) for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to guide you without giving you any code to help you learn, you should probably start from scratch I think and make sure you know how each part of your code works.

Some things about primes, 1 isn't prime and 2 is so you should start with a=3 and print 2 immediately if you want to eliminate even numbers.

By doing that, you will then be able to just increment a by 2 rather than 1 as you're doing now and just skip over even numbers.

As you loop a to be less than 100, you need to check if each value of a is prime by making another loop with another variable that loops downward through all numbers that could possibly divide a (less than or equal to a's square root).  If that variable divides a, then exit the inner loop and increment a, but if it makes it all the way to 1, then a is prime and you should print it, then increment a.

Answer (score 0):

There's several things wrong with what you're doing here:

- You don't find the first 100 primes, you find the primes less than 100 with `while a < 100`
- You `print a` every time `a` is evenly divisble by `i`, and then increment `a`.  But you've gotten ahead of yourself!  `a` is prime only if it is not divisble by *any* value `i`, but you fail to keep track of whether it's failed for any `i`.
- You add +1 to the range up to the square root of the number - but that's not necessary.  The square root of the number is the largest number that could possibly be the smaller of two factors.  You don't need to add 1 because that number is _bigger than the sqare root - in other words, if a is evenly divisble by sqrt(a)+1 , then a / (sqrt(a)+1) will be smaller than sqrt(a)+1 and therfore would have already been found.
- You never print the list of primes you found; you `print a` every time you find a number that is not a  factor ( primes have *no* factors other than one and themselves, so you're not printing prime numbers at all!)

This might get you thinking in the right direction:

```
a=0
primes = []
while len(primes) < 100:
  a = a + 1
  prime=True
  maxfactor = int(a ** .5)
  for i in primes:
    if i == 1:
      continue
    if i > maxfactor:
      break
    if a % i == 0:
      print a, " is not prime because it is evenly divisble by ", i
      prime=False
      break
  if prime:
    print "Prime number: ", a
    primes.append(a)
for p in primes:
    print p
```